# Multiple App Users Accessing A Private Database In CloudKit

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I am in the process of designing an app for a small family business.  There are three to four users of this app and the plan is to share the data.  I have designed this app based off the example code in the book "iOS APPS for Masterminds ios12" Chapter 23 in the Local Cache section.
The example code sets up a private database in CloudKit and the idea is all the data is stored there.  Also, core data is set up to save the data downloaded from CloudKit to the users device.  Any changes made to the data on the users device are then sent to CloudKit and both devices are in sync.  Any other user with the app installed on their device will do the same.  I can get this app to work on my device and make data changes in CloudKit and the changes are updated on the device and vise versa, but when I install the app on a different users device, the data doesn't get downloaded from CloudKit and any changes on that device are not reflected in CloudKit.  Both my iPhone and the other user's iPhone are registered in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section of my Apple Developer's Account.  Not sure why this is not working, looking for anyone who has had a similar app or problem with getting this to work with multiple users.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Private DB is not accessible to any other user by design.

You need to use Shared DB, see more here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1640408-sharedclouddatabase

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no good way to have multiple users share a database in CloudKit. The "shared database" just creates pointers to records back in each user's private database.